# Vs code environment variables are causing me alot of issues. Is this because I am on windows?

Tags: windows

[my .env code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS4gn.png)

I am following this tutorial https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ and think my .env might be why I am getting this error Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID' because I have tried all other troubleshooting methods I have found. Please Help I have been trying to figure this out for over 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

well, I skipped a large part of the tutorial accidentally and never added
dotenv: .env
wallets:
from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
to my script. Also, make sure your .env file is using plane text or else you will get errors